# Is CTRL+C incorrect to use to return to command line?

Tags: linux, bash

When I'm using `tail -f` and I want to return to the shell, I always use `CTRL+C`. Or when I am typing a command and feel like aborting it and starting over, I simply `CTRL+C` to get back to an empty command line prompt. Is this considered bad practice? I sometimes feel there might be a better way to break away from something, but really have no idea.

Comment: To cancel a partially entered shell command, you can use Control-U or Delete (depending on your tty settings and key bindings), but there's nothing wrong with using Control-C.

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for the Ctrl+U, I wasnt aware of that one :-)

Comment: For the record, C-u doesn't actually *cancel* the command entered, it moves it to the paste buffer (similar to the "cut" functionality of some programs).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT to the program. This tells the program that you want to interrupt (and end) it's process. Most programs correctly catch this and cleanly exit. So, yes, this is a "correct" way to end most programs.

There are other keyboard shortcuts for sending other signals to programs, but this is the most common.

Comment: There's also Ctrl+D for programs that are reading input from the user. Ctrl+D closes STDIN to the program. For gracefully exiting the shell this is also available (exact same as typing exit).

Comment: @Patrick Ctrl+D actually sends an End of File indicator to the stream. It's up to the program to respond appropriately (usually closing the file stream).

Comment: thats what closing STDIN does. You cant get EOF without the  pipe/stream being closed.

Comment: Wrong on three counts, Patrick.  First: Control+D doesn't have this meaning for pipes.  Second: the EOF special character doesn't close anything.  It causes a _one time_ return of zero bytes (presuming that the line buffer is empty) from the current `read()` system call.  The next `read()`s are unaffected.  Third: **None of this applies** to programs which put the line discipline into non-canonical mode, such as _most shell programs_ from the past couple of decades and indeed any other program that uses a library such as GNU `readline`.

Answer (score 13):

This method is just fine, really.

Answer (score 11):

To abort a long command while typing, I sometimes jump to the start of line, and insert a comment sign, before hitting enter:

<kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Pos1</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>

This is useful, if I typed a copy command with a long path, for example, and meanwhile observe, that I first need to create the directory, but would like to repeat the command afterwards. Then I just have to take it from the history, delete the hash, and enter it.

In Bash, you can use the shortcut

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>

to remarkify your command, as pointed out in the comments (Thanks, @Zorawar).

Comment: You can also use `Ctrl-A` without taking your fingers off the home row.

Comment: And `Ctrl-E` goes to the end, by the way.

Comment: @Dave: That's right, but you don't need to move to the end to hit enter, to confirm your command. The commandline is not an editor, where this might insert a newline.

Comment: In bash you can achieve the same thing by just pressing `Alt-#`: it will put the comment in and run the command (so putting it in your history).

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is fine when the program offers you no interactive way to terminate (either by design, or, more frequently, because it has frozen or become unusable). Just bear in mind that, when in interactive mode, the key combo you really want may be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, which sends an `EOF`, signaling the end of the input.

Answer (score 1):

If using Bash, one can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, and type `bg` to "put the current job in background".

Answer (score 0):

As @Patrick said in the comment on the accepted answer,

> There's also `Ctrl+D` for programs that are reading input from the user. `Ctrl+D` closes STDIN to the program.

This helped me when `Ctrl+C` did not work to get the command line back after using `>>`