# Windows shell Escape key (delete whole line) equivalent in Bash

Tags: bash, command-line

In Windows command line (powershell and cmd), when you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key while on a line, whatever you have typed at the prompt is removed.

I found that pressing `Esc` key at bash prompt does nothing. Pressing `Esc` and then `backspace` deletes a word, but this has to be done for each word.

I am learning Bash incrementally and sometimes type something stupid in the middle of the line and feel that it is better to type from scratch again. To do this, pressing `backspace` is the only way I found until now.

What do you do?

I am aware of the `clear` command and <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> shortcut, but I am not talking about clearing the entire terminal. Just the line.

Comment: A while back I posted a [list of useful readline keyboard shortcuts](http://superuser.com/a/322443/92173) on superuser.  You may find them useful as well.  (Readline is the library that bash uses for line-editing.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want **`kill-whole-line`**, but this is not bound by default in bash. **`backward-kill-line`** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) and **`unix-line-discard`** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>) both erase from the current point to the beginning of the line, so just go to the end of the line and use either.

Comment: You are correct, it is not bound to anything. I just found out that using `bind -P`. I guess `Ctrl-U` and then `Ctrl-Y` is the only option then.

Comment: You'll find that a number of the default bindings are derived from the key sequences in the Emacs editor and that those bindings show up elsewhere, too.

Comment: @Blrfl to extend your comment, most of these keybindings have been abstracted into the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library, which a large number commandline programs use and which is why they all have similar line editing keys.

Answer (score 16):

You could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to abandon whatever you were typing and get an empty new command line, see [Is CTRL+C incorrect to use to return to command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29654/is-ctrlc-incorrect-to-use-to-return-to-command-line).

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> goes to the beginning of the line and <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> deletes to the end of the line

Comment: Try `^U` first, in most Emacs command line editing mode implementations it already deletes the full line. In those where it only deletes left from the cursor (GNU readline, for example), press `^K` afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer a little, you can get (almost) Windows-like behaviour from the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in bash by binding the `kill-whole-line` to <kbd>Esc</kbd> with the following command

```
bind '"\e":kill-whole-line'
```

If you add the line to your `~/.inputrc` file, the binding will persist between sessions.

Note, however, that this is *very* non-standard, as bash actually uses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key as another modifying key (like a non-persistent Alt or Ctrl). If you look at the list of existing key bindings (with `bind -P`), you will likely see several commands bound to key-combinations that start with "\e" (e.g.

```
"\eb": backward-word
```

which sets up the combination <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to move the cursor back to the most recent word-beginning – rather like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, except that you have to keep releasing <kbd>Esc</kbd> (as well as <kbd>B</kbd>, of course) if you want to do it more than once in a row).

And that explains why I said that the behaviour you get is *almost* Windows-like: when you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, bash checks to see if you're using it in combination with another key; so, if you bind it to `kill-whole-line`, there's a bit of a delay between pressing (or rather, releasing) <kbd>Esc</kbd> and bash clearing the line for you.

However, if you don't care about any of that, and would rather live with the delay than retrain yourself to a different keystroke, it can be done.

(Note: much of the information here I got as a result of reading – and following the links in – [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/220590/190390).)

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks, and works more-or-less as advertised.  But I did find it produced some annoying behaviour when *other* commands are executed "invalidly", such as pressing DEL when at the end of a line: This would clear the line and replace it with `[19;` or a similar-looking escape code.  In the end I found mapping `"\e\e"` to `kill-whole-line` (i.e., tap Esc twice to clear the line) a nice compromise.

Comment: @j_random_hacker : Hm, I like that. I often hit `Esc` a few times anyway, so I might try that. I currently have it bound to `Ctrl`+`Del` but I never remember that.

Comment: I struggled to make this work for my `.inputrc` on Mac. It turns out I didn't need the bind command at the beginning, i.e., just do `"\e\e": kill-whole-line`.
BTW, thanks @j_random_hacker for that double-escape tip - it's awesome!